# How do i store the e.target in a variable?

Tags: javascript, dom

When the input(checked box) is clicked I want the textarea to have a border 2px solid green.
The user can add more checkboxes and texareas. The problem is how to I store the texarea in a variable to then style it?
CODE

```
 <div class="container">
    <h1 class="title">Question 1</h1>
    <textarea type="checkbox" name="question" id="q1" cols="30" rows="5">How old am I?</textarea> <br><br>
    <input type="checkbox"><textarea class='ans' type="checkbox" name="question"  cols="30" rows="5">Whay is your name</textarea> <br><br>
    <input type="checkbox"><textarea class='ans'type="checkbox" name="question"  cols="30" rows="5">What is your name</textarea> <br><br>
    <input type="checkbox"><textarea class='ans'type="checkbox" name="question" cols="30" rows="5">Whatv</textarea> <br><br>
    <button onclick="getButton()">Add an option</button>
  </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
let button = document.querySelector('button');
let container = document.querySelector('.container');
let textArea;
let getButton = () => {
  // create input
  const input = document.createElement('input');
  // add type to input
  input.type = 'checkbox';
  // create textarea
  textArea = document.createElement('textarea');
  // add name to textArea
  textArea.name = 'question';
  // add className
  textArea.className = 'ans'
  // cols
  textArea.cols = 30;
  // rows
  textArea.rows = 5;
  // insert into the container
  container.insertBefore(input, button)
  container.insertBefore(textArea, button)  
}

container.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  test = e.currentTarget.tagName;
  if(e.target.value === '' && e.target.tagName === 'TEXTAREA'){
    console.log('I am empty');
  } else if(e.target.tagName === 'TEXTAREA'){
    console.log(e.target.value);
  }
})

container.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  if(e.target.tagName === 'INPUT' || e.target.tagName === 'TEXTAREA'){

  }
})
```

Comment: If you want that variable to be accessible globally, you can use `window.yourVariable = <value>`. However, I think a better idea is to define it at `container` element context.

Comment: how can I store the text areas the user creates into a variable? I am new to this. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @AlexRodriguez Here is a solution to your question about getting coinciding employees: https://replit.com/@ShashSinha1/Nodejs-6#index.js

Answer (score 0):

I use `nextSibling` to solve you probelm:

```js
let button = document.querySelector('button');
let container = document.querySelector('.container');
let textArea;
let getButton = () => {
  // create input
  const input = document.createElement('input');
  // add type to input
  input.type = 'checkbox';
  // create textarea
  textArea = document.createElement('textarea');
  // add name to textArea
  textArea.name = 'question';
  // add className
  textArea.className = 'ans'
  // cols
  textArea.cols = 30;
  // rows
  textArea.rows = 5;
  // insert into the container
  container.insertBefore(input, button)
  container.insertBefore(textArea, button)  
}

container.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  test = e.currentTarget.tagName;
  if(e.target.value === '' && e.target.tagName === 'TEXTAREA'){
    console.log('I am empty');
  } else if(e.target.tagName === 'TEXTAREA'){
    console.log(e.target.value);
  } else if(e.target.tagName === 'INPUT'){
      e.target.nextSibling.style.border = e.target.checked? '2px solid green' : '';
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="title">Question 1</h1>
    <textarea type="checkbox" name="question" id="q1" cols="30" rows="5">How old am I?</textarea> <br><br>
    <input type="checkbox"><textarea class='ans' type="checkbox" name="question"  cols="30" rows="5">Whay is your name</textarea> <br><br>
    <input type="checkbox"><textarea class='ans'type="checkbox" name="question"  cols="30" rows="5">What is your name</textarea> <br><br>
    <input type="checkbox"><textarea class='ans'type="checkbox" name="question" cols="30" rows="5">Whatv</textarea> <br><br>
    <button onclick="getButton()">Add an option</button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your question, but you can store the HTML of the element using `outerHTML`:

```
let yourVariable = e.target.outerHTML;
```

You can then create a new element, append it to the DOM, and set its HTML to `yourVariable`.